#  Error in Dynamic Query near  ','. -.-

Tags: c#, dynamic-sql

i can't figure out why this isnt working.

I'm using Dynamic SQL

Here is how i generate the SQL Statement:

```
OLD: SET @dSQL = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT([' + @TableName + '], RESEED, 0); SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' +                                                            @TableName + ' ON; INSERT INTO ' + @thisTable +  '(' + @pkcolumns + ', '+  @columns + ')' + ' SELECT (' + @pkcolumns + ', '+  @columns + ') FROM ' + @oldTable +' GROUP BY ' + @pkcolumns + '; SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' OFF;'

NEW: SET @dSQL = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT([' + @TableName + '], RESEED, 0); SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' ON; INSERT INTO ' + @thisTable +  @pkcolumns + ', '+  @columns  + ' SELECT DISTINCT(' + @pkcolumns + '), '+  @columns + ' FROM ' + @oldTable + '; SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' OFF;'
```

As is execute the procedure the variables are like this.

```
@TableName DATA.HTI
@thisTable DATA.HTI
@oldTable [OR_JTU_2530].DATA.HTI

@columns [PARENT_HTI_ID], [OPERATION], [DISPLAY], [ACTIVE], [OFFSET]
@pkcolumns [HTI_ID]

@dSQL DBCC CHECKIDENT([DATA.HTI], RESEED, 0); SET IDENTITY_INSERT DATA.HTI ON; INSERT INTO DATA.HTI([HTI_ID], [PARENT_HTI_ID], [OPERATION], [DISPLAY], [ACTIVE], [OFFSET]) SELECT ([KPI_ID], [PARENT_KPI_ID], [OPERATION], [DISPLAY], [ACTIVE], [OFFSET]) FROM [OR_JTU_2530].DATA.HTI GROUP BY [HTI_ID]; SET IDENTITY_INSERT DATA.HTI OFF;
```

UPDATE:
**Group by removed, distinct inserted**

Answer (score 3):

If you print out your string, you'll see that this:

```
SELECT (' + @pkcolumns + ', '+  @columns + ') FROM
```

Generates something like:

```
SELECT (column1,column2,column3) FROM
```

Which isn't valid syntax. Once you fix that (by removing the `()` brackets), however, you'll still have an issue, because you're doing a `GROUP BY` on your `@pkcolumns`, but the `@columns` columns aren't included in the `GROUP BY` or by any aggregate, so you'll still get an error.

Comment: Actually it gets me something like that SELECT ([column1],[column2],[column3]) FROM, but you are right with the group by i changed it to disctinct and removed the () and only left it to the distinct

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if it works or not based on the new code you have posted above:

```
SET @dSQL = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT([' + @TableName + '], RESEED, 0); 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' ON; INSERT INTO ' + @thisTable + '(' + @pkcolumns + ', ' + @columns + ') SELECT DISTINCT ' + @pkcolumns + ', ' +  @columns + ' FROM ' + @oldTable + ' 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' OFF;'
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can post here the generated SQL Statement for @dSQL? This will help us find the issue quickly...